# Relating an Email Message To Task is it Possible?

Tags: apex-email-service

I have a requirement that involves an email service. In the email service I should be Creating a Task (Done) and creating an email message and put it as a related Object Under the Task that is created.

Apparently, upon testing it I always have an error . I have tried to do the follow codes:

```
 em.ParentId = taskId;
 em.RelatedToId = taskId;
 em.ActivityId = taskId;
```

The ParentId is throwing an error because Task isn't part of the list of objectsthat ParentId has a look up to.

RelatedToId Throws me this error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Related To ID: id value of incorrect type: 00TBo000000SesBMAS: [RelatedToId]

The Activity Id Throws me this error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, You cannot edit this field: [ActivityId]

Anythoughts about this ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the emailMessage object [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) ,

`ParentId` refers to the `case` object alone.

`RelatedToId` refer to other standard objects like below and task is not available.

> Account, Accreditation, AssessmentIndicatorDefinition, AssessmentTask,
> AssessmentTaskContentDocument, AssessmentTaskDefinition,
> AssessmentTaskOrder, Asset, AssetRelationship, AssignedResource,
> Award, BoardCertification, BusinessLicense, BusinessMilestone,
> BusinessProfile, Campaign, CareBarrier, CareBarrierDeterminant,
> CareBarrierType, CareDeterminant, CareDeterminantType, CareDiagnosis,
> CareInterventionType, CareMetricTarget, CareObservation,
> CareObservationComponent, CarePgmProvHealthcareProvider, CarePreauth,
> CarePreauthItem, CareProgram, CareProgramCampaign,
> CareProgramEligibilityRule, CareProgramEnrollee,
> CareProgramEnrolleeProduct, CareProgramEnrollmentCard,
> CareProgramGoal, CareProgramProduct, CareProgramProvider,
> CareProgramTeamMember, CareProviderAdverseAction,
> CareProviderFacilitySpecialty, CareProviderSearchableField,
> CareRegisteredDevice, CareRequest, CareRequestDrug,
> CareRequestExtension, CareRequestItem, CareSpecialty,
> CareSpecialtyTaxonomy, CareTaxonomy, Case, CommSubscriptionConsent,
> ContactEncounter, ContactEncounterParticipant, ContactRequest,
> Contract, CoverageBenefit, CoverageBenefitItem, CreditMemo,
> DelegatedAccount, DocumentChecklistItem,
> EnrollmentEligibilityCriteria, HealthcareFacility,
> HealthcareFacilityNetwork, HealthcarePayerNetwork,
> HealthcarePractitionerFacility, HealthcareProvider,
> HealthcareProviderNpi, HealthcareProviderSpecialty,
> HealthcareProviderTaxonomy, IdentityDocument, Image,
> IndividualApplication, Invoice, ListEmail, Location, MemberPlan,
> Opportunity, Order, OtherComponentTask, PartyConsent, PersonLifeEvent,
> PlanBenefit, PlanBenefitItem, ProcessException, Product2, ProductItem,
> ProductRequest, ProductRequestLineItem, ProductTransfer,
> PurchaserPlan, ReceivedDocument, ResourceAbsence, ReturnOrder,
> ReturnOrderLineItem, ServiceAppointment, ServiceResource, Shift,
> Shipment, ShipmentItem, Solution, Visit, VisitedParty,
> VolunteerProject, WorkOrder, WorkOrderLineItem

ActivityId :

> ID of the activity that is associated with the email. Usually
> represents an open task that is created for the case owner when a new
> unread email message is received. ActivityId can only be specified for
> emails on cases. It’s auto-created for other entities.

You can't able to link a task to `emailMessage`

Answer (score 0):

Only objects that have an Activity History can be a parent